# Mysql two points to be checked if they are in rectangles

Tags: mysql, maps, routes

I'm in a process of developing an application and I would appreciate some help regarding an idea how to store data in mysql table.

I have two points - point A and point B which are start and end point.
I've already wrote some php function that will create rectangles similar to:
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/search-along-route-made-easy-with.html

However depending on the route and radius it generates different amount of rectangles. What is the best way to save those rectangles into the database, so later I can query the DB and check if another two points (start/end) are in any of those rectangles.

Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to store your rectangles as polygons, per 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/polygon-property-functions.html

You can then use MBRIntersects to figure out if they intersect (or use MBRWithin or MBRContains, if you'd prefer), per
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_mbrintersects

For funky-shaped polygons, this isn't adequate, but the MBR (minimum bounding box) of a rectangular bounding box will be exactly the same as the rectangle itself.